# How do I globally import Tabs in docusaurus.config.js in Docusaurus 2, so that I don't have to import them in every file?

Tags: tabs, docusaurus

That I don't have to import

```
import Tabs from '@theme/Tabs';
import TabItem from '@theme/TabItem';
```

in every file.

To solve my issue, I added the code in docusaurus.config.js

```js
const Tabs = require('@theme/Tabs').Tabs;
const TabItem = require('@theme/TabItem').TabItem;
```

below

```js
const lightCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/github');
const darkCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/dracula');
```

Then

```js
      customFields: {
        tabs: {
          tabsComponent: 'Tabs',
          tabComponent: 'TabItem',
        },
      },
```

in `themeConfig:({})`

Here is the error I am getting

```
[ERROR] Error: These field(s) ("tabs",) are not recognized in docusaurus.config.js.
If you still want these fields to be in your configuration, put them in the "customFields" field.
See https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config/#customfields
    at validateConfig (/Docusaurus/pro/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/configValidation.js:228:15)
    at loadSiteConfig (/Docusaurus/pro/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/config.js:40:62)
    at async loadContext (/Docusaurus/pro/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/index.js:31:63)
    at async load (/Docusaurus/pro/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/index.js:74:21)
    at async Command.start (/Docusaurus/pro/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/start.js:44:19)
```

@docusaurus/theme-common installed

If you ask, I can provide the full config